# Eclipse doesn't automatically add servlets to web.xml?

Tags: eclipse, servlets, automation

I used to use Eclipse Galileo, but now I have Helios.  Galileo used to automatically add my servlets to `web.xml`, but in Helios I have to do this myself.

Is there something I can configure to make this automatic again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This hasn't been changed. Most likely you have used *New > Class* instead of *New > Servlet* to create the servlet.

Comment: I'm sure it's a servlet. I just tried it on my laptop and it works properly, so it's some kind of local problem i guess. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please note that when you have created a dynamic web project with Servlet 3.0 facet, but didn't tick the *Generate deployment descriptor* checkbox at end of project creation wizard, then a `web.xml` won't be created and instead the servlets will get the `@WebServlet` annotation. But your question didn't give the impression that the `web.xml` was physically absent.

Comment: Yes, web.xml is here with only <welcome-file-list>. The strange thing is that on my laptop when a make a servlet it works, but it's not in web.xml. If i add the servlet by myself, it works again but it's so confusing for me, how it can work when it's not in web.xml. The other thing I've changed is that I migrated from Tomcat 6 to 7 but it don't have to be a problem... I guess.

Comment: Since Servlet 3.0, servlets can be mapped by the `@WebServlet` annotation above the class instead of by `web.xml`. Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 container.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks. What do I need to have, besides `tomcat 7` and `eclipse java ee`,  to use annotations like `@webservlet` ? Is there an `annotations jar` like we have in `hibernate` ? I haven't tried tom 7 yet. Still forced to use tom 6 since my textbook uses it.

Comment: Perhaps useful to clarify BalusC's comments to say that at least currently you can have a `web.xml` (by default for me in Eclipse Mars, it lists `welcome-file`s) **and** have Eclipse use annotations instead of pushing mappings and names into `web.xml`.

Comment: @BalusC It might be worth 1.) removing that first comment ("Please note...") if it no longer applies and 2.) Pushing the new info into the answer. I really like your answer [on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854907/1028230) better, and wonder if it isn't worth closing [this as a dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/184684) now. ??

Answer (score 6):

this post will help you ..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14854907/1847899

"Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. Since Servlet 3.0, the servlets can be configured by @WebServlet annotation on the class without the need for a web.xml configuration entry."

Answer (score 4):

You need to change some settings on the project:

1. Create dynamic project
2. Right-click on name of dynamic project
3. Create servlet name and click `Next` (not `Finish)

   - The URL mapping will show
4. Click on `Add` and give it the name you used in web.xml (like /mohan)

   - By default it  will be  name of servlet
5. Click on remove
6. Remove the default URL mapping name

Now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to worry about that Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. Since Servlet 3.0, the servlets can be configured by @WebServlet annotation on the class there is no need for a web.xml configuration entry.If you are still confused just change the "dynamic web module version" to 2.5 instead of 3.0 at this point... new-> dynamic web project. then you can see that your servlets will be configured in web.xml automatically