# Not getting automatically web.xml file while creating servlet in Eclipse Juno 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am using Eclipse Juno 4.2, Java 1.7 and Tomcat 7. But in my system when I create  servlet the `web.xml` file doesn't create automatically, but another system it's create automatically `web.xml` file. I am totally confused, is there anything to configure?

I also add `web.xml` file when I am going to create a dynamic project.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Tomcat 7 is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. Since Servlet 3.0, the servlets can be configured by `@WebServlet` annotation on the class without the need for a `web.xml` configuration entry. Look closer at the servlet class you just created, there's a `@WebServlet` annotation on it containing all information you specified in *New Servlet* wizard.

Effectively, this new way of configuring servlets

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

does exactly the same as this legacy way of configuring servlets

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you still want Eclipse to create a `web.xml` entry for some reason, then you should change the *Dynamic Web Module* version back from 3.0 to 2.5 in *Project Facets* section of project's properties.

Comment: But that annotation does not work without further tweaks on tomcat 7. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669507/embedded-tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-annotations-not-working

Comment: @arun Please don't confuse "Embedded Tomcat" with "Tomcat". The current question is about Tomcat, the question you linked is about Embedded Tomcat which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: will the `@WebServlet` tag work even when multiple servlets are being used?

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks, the explanation helped. However, is it possible to configure Eclipse - to create web.xml and to add Servlet entries as response to new `@WebServlet` annotations - for backward compatibility? (In case I want to deploy the application with Servlet 2.5)

Comment: @NShomik: Just set dynamic web project facet version to 2.5.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks. I guess this is going to the solution for me. For some reason though my Eclipse (Mars) is not allowing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Servlet 2.5 version instead of the 3.0 then web.xml will automatically be updated to contain the servlets you created.